# Form Authentication Cookie is expiring on each request in bigrock shared hosting

Tags: forms, cookies, forms-authentication, expired-sessions

Cookie is resetting for every request on shared hosting in bigrock. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

It's working good in dev environement. Not sure why this issue's occuring after hosted.

Any help ?

Please find the cookie and authentication details below

In Development Environment

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="xxxx.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

In Hosting Environment

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/"    requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" domain=".xxxxx.com" />
</authentication
```

In Development Environement

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" />
```

In Hosting Environment

```
<sessionState stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

cookieless="false" timeout="240" />

In Development Environment

```
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1536000" executionTimeout="5400" maxQueryStringLength="16384" />
```

In Hosting Environment

```
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1536000" executionTimeout="14400" maxQueryStringLength="16384" />
  <trust level="Medium" />
  <machineKey validationKey="B8095B36FC8FEBF6F93DF08E976E88DE969EB2157706A0F0A6DD67D1C1EF5DAB6035B2613EC05C9FF3F7A531D7462F0EED44453C4626A9E1FDBCD596AEFD1BB3" decryptionKey="512BBBCD3B92652675334E317B7F3FBF9F36112D4F23091C67B1479CE1E96976" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

Fiddler Log Information

```
 ![Fiddler Info][1]
```

Comment: Here at Network Solution we had a long day with this issue, and finally we expertise and solved this specific problem (Session expiring and specified timeout is ignored) at server configuration level.

Result of our work is a shared server where hosted created apps can be always-logged, thanks to our server config scripts (made in years of expertise), preconfigured also with the SessionState DB custom database if you want, the ideal for Windows-IIS-ASP.NET-MSSQL shared hosting!


Please contact me at marco.marsala AT live.it to see if our solution is applicable in your case

Comment: Fed up with issue !! so finally i bought Virutal Private Server.Thanks Marco Marsala